# Border overlapping issue

Tags: css, html, border

I have two `div`s. The top one has a different `border-bottom`, but it is overlapping the border on the right side. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zu4p8/9/) if you look closely.

Is there a way to restrict the border to within the left and right borders?

Comment: This has nothing to do with border width.

Comment: Prepared for the outside DIV border to frame, inside the DIV, you have a border.

Comment: If you increase the size of the border, it's more clear how borders are rendered in the browser. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zu4p8/11/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've divined your meaning.  You don't want the bottom border to overlap the side borders?  You'll have to put your divs in a container and apply the border to that container:

http://jsfiddle.net/zu4p8/10/